# image size issue with three20 photo browser?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I face following problem with three20 photobrowser app :

1: Some time images are of cutoff the screen 320x480, so that image are not fit in view and some what in left and right side.when you zoom in than you can see the exact image.

2: How to set default image to another thumbnail image ?

Did any one modified the code for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find out the solution of my first problem. here you can go and change the code or download the latest code"

http://github.com/tupil/three20/commit/416d6f1f57b1f7fa1ee99d8100beb6399b69cf8d

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my fix was this:

```
[images addObject: [[[TTPhoto alloc] initWithURL: imageURL
                                        smallURL: thumbnailURL]
                                            size: CGSizeMake(0, 0)] autorelease]];
```

The trick is the `CGSizeMake(0, 0)` that makes the image scale to the size of the view.

Regarding your second question, which is the 'default' image you're talking about?

Comment: Yupppp !!! for my first question i am giving CGSizeZero.

Second question , while loading the image till the image loaded completely, its showing a default image (some thing like a box) in blue color .i want same as facebook (till original image loaded show thumnail image which is also pulled fromserver).